# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input on popup.html file in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome Extension for the first time. When I right click the extension icon and inspect the popup this is the error I'm getting.

> **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input** *myextension*/popup.html

And the fact that it's failing on an HTML file is making me confused. I looked through about 10 other similar questions and most of the time it's apparently a syntax error in the javascript file. I've linted mine with a couple different linters and still nothing is showing up. Could somebody help me spot a mistake here? It's 62 lines:

```
function updatePopup(){
    listofbad = JSON.parse(localStorage["badguys"]);
    $('#dumpster').empty();
    var i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < listofbad.length; i = i+1){
        $('#dumpster').append( listofbad[i] + "<br>");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    if(localStorage["badguys"] != undefined){
        var namesthe = JSON.parse(localStorage["badguys"]);
        updatePopup();
        chrome.tabs.query({
            active: true,
            currentWindow: true
            },
            function(tabs) {
                /* ...and send a request for the DOM info... */
                console.log("Sending message from popup to content");
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
                        tabs[0].id,
                        {from: 'popup', subject: 'DOMInfo', newnames: namesthe}
                );
            }
        );
    }
});

function save_options() {
    var thenames = [];
    if( localStorage["badguys"] != undefined ){
        thenames = JSON.parse(localStorage["badguys"]);
    }
    console.log("JSONParse: " + thenames.toString());
    //thenames = ["Aidenator", "Moobot", "Nightbot", "Teamevilmaster"];
    var elname = document.getElementById("namebox").value;
    if( $.inArray(elname, thenames) > -1 ){
        return false;
    }
    thenames.push(elname);
    localStorage["badguys"] = JSON.stringify(thenames);
    updatePopup();
    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    }, function(tabs) {
        /* ...and send a request for the DOM info... */
        console.log("Sending message from popup to content");
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
                tabs[0].id,
                {from: 'popup', subject: 'DOMInfo', newnames: thenames}
        );
    });
}
document.getElementById('namebutton').addEventListener('click', save_options);

function clearlist() {
    localStorage["badguys"] = [];
    updatePopup();
}
document.getElementById('clearbutton').addEventListener('click', clearlist );
```

---

Here's the small HTML that goes along with it too:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>Extension Options</title>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='status'></div>
    Annoying person's name:
    <input type='text' id="namebox"></input>
    <button id="namebutton">Add</button>
    <button id="clearbutton">Clear List</button>
    <hr>
    <center>
        <i>List of Removed People:</i>
    </center>
    <div id="dumpster"></div>
    <hr>
    <center>
        <img src="carlton.jpg" width="50px">
    </center>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe I've been staring at a screen too long to spot any typos, but if somebody could help me out here, that'd be great. This Chrome Extension business has been quite frustrating.

Comment: some syntax error. check by adding each function one by one to the code till you figure it out.

Comment: @RobW I do not see the missing closing brace. The brace you're thinking of is in the same column as "function(tabs)". And I checked and there's an even amount of braces and parenthesis in my code, so I don't think it's a missing brace. Possible a misplaced one though. Any more suggestions? I'll try plugging in each function one by one till I get some more clues.

Comment: This error is generated by using `JSON.parse` on a non-JSON string. Fix it.

Comment: You were totally right. I was parsing JSON from an empty key in localStorage. So I just had to add more error checking to see if the key or value in localStorage was empty. Now it works!